# How would you create a Fancy Panel which applies extra styles?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like a FancyPanel Control that automatically applies styles the content in it, for example

```
<asp:FancyPanel runat="server" id="pnl1">
    <Header>
      Header Text
    </Header>
    <Body>
        //any regular aspx markup
    </Body>
    <Footer>
        Footer Text
    </Footer>
</asp:FancyPanel>
```

So basically when this gets rendered I can now wrap everything in the header in a div with a bold text style and add rounded corners (I don't need advice for styling, just the FancyPanel side of things, an empty div is good enough). All the Header, Body and Footer need to be able to accept regular server controls to be embedded in them.

How do I create this type of control?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, then you need [template custom control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478964.aspx).